# How to integrate with OpenFire XMPP server to receive roster info for users?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I need to create small auxiliary server that is part/integrates with OpenFire server in order to get roster for a given user.

I was looking for some plugin/api call that given the user JID to return his contacts and their online status.

All-in-all I may end up changing OpenFire's code but I was hoping that there is a easier solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All though the links provided by Manasi would work for you. However those links  refers to user service plugin which has been depricated by openfire.

They recommend to use [REST API plugin](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html).

You'll see list of all plugins [here](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp).

You should read about [retrieving user roster](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#retrieve-user-roster) and their [presence](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/presence/readme.html) .

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the user service plugin of openfire that returns a host of information of the user as well as its rosters.

for documentation click [here.](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html)

You can get the roster information by [this url.](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html#get-userserviceusersusernameroster)